# How to find tag bit in cache given word address

Tags: caching, cpu-word, memory-address

> Caches are important to providing a high-performance memory hierarchy
> to processors. Below is a list of 32-bit memory address references,
> given as word addresses.
>
> 3, 180, 43, 2, 191, 88, 190, 14, 181, 44, 186, 253
>
> For each of these references, identify the binary address, the tag,
> and the index given a direct-mapped cache with two-word blocks and a
> total size of 8 blocks. Also list if each reference is a hit or a
> miss, assuming the cache is initially empty.

the answer is :
[image]

I understood that it was to find tag, index, and offset values ​​from the 32-bit memory address value and use it in the cache table, but I do not understand well that the memory address is given as a word. For example, does the word address 3 actually mean `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011`? Given a word address, how can it be thought of as a 32-bit address in the figure below?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the word address 3 (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011), the offset would be 1, the index would be 001, and the tag would be 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000.

- 2 words in block = 1 bit
  for offset (2^1).
- 8 blocks in cache = 3 bits for index (2^3).
- 32 - 4 = 28 bits for tag.