# Why don't we need to subtract byte offset bits in this problem?

Tags: caching, bit, memory-address, cpu-word

In the following question :[How to find tag bit in cache given word address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325412/how-to-find-tag-bit-in-cache-given-word-address)

They have found the number of tag bits by `32 - number of index bits  - word offset`. But in the book, they also mentioned the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49DrC.png)

Why are we not subtracting 2 here in the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is getting confused like me, it is as follows as far as I know.

Given word address `3`, we can convert it to by address which is one of address between `12` and `15` inclusive because word is 4 bytes and thus you have to multiply word address by 4.

If you convert `12` and `15` to binary it will be `...001100` and `...001111` and you have to get least `2` significant bits for byte offset and the next `1` bit for word( block) offset which leaves `001` in both cases.